# When pressing the SUPER key the DASH takes a while to appear

Tags: 11.10, unity-dash

When pressing the SUPER key, the Dash takes a while to appear. I know it is being recognized since I can leave it pressed and the shortcut numbers for the icons in the launcher appear but when I press it the Dash takes a lot to appear (between 10 seconds to a full minute). This sometimes gets worse if I have Firefox opened but in this case everything is closed. I even restarted the PC just to make sure.

Is there an option to see how long the dash should take to appear or something similar.

Comment: Do you still have the same problem when you use <Alt> F2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd guess that your computer is slow. You could disable the dynamic blur that the dash uses and see if it no opens faster. You can do this in `ccsm` under Unity. There you can switch between the currently used blur, static blur and none. I'd recommend using none.

Comment: Hi, I have already done that and there has been no real improvement. I guess the opacity of the Dash is also a problem